# how to using include tag frequently?

Tags: java, android

I have a layout .xml file and I want to use it frequently (20 times)within another xml file.
of course with different Initializing.i dont want to use include tags for 20 and init 20 times.Is there any way instead of add include tag for 20 times?

Comment: Since 20 of something may not fit all screen sizes, consider using a `RecyclerView`, with your layout forming the basis of the items inside the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Then create custom view

Create custom class extending any **[ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup)** like `LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout` etc and handled your code depending on conditions.

```
public class YourCustomImpl extends LinearLayout {
...
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_common_view, this, true);
...
}
```

Include your custom implemented view  like below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...

    <your.domain.YourCustomImpl
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For more details there is nice **[tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)**